# $K/k$ Galois with group $\mathfrak{g}$, $V_{K} \cong V_{k} \otimes K$. Then, $V_{k}$ consists of elements of $V_{K}$ invariant under $\mathfrak{g}$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, classical-groups

I have been asked to read "*Andre A. Weil. Algebras with involutions and the classical groups. J. Indian Math. Soc.(N.S.) 24 (1960), 589–623*" as part of a project, and I am encountering some difficulties with some notations and notions used by Weil, in particular, the notion of a *universal domain*.

In the first page of the paper itself, Weil says

> In Part I, all spaces, varieties, groups are.......allowed to have points in the universal domain, and not only in their field of definition. If $V$ is a variety defined over a field $k$, we shall denote by $V_{k}$ the set of points of $V$ with coordinates in $k$.

I think I understand what this means here, but I am confused when he carries the same thing for vector spaces for instance, later he says

> If $V$ is a vector space of dimension $n$ (over the universal domain) defined over $k$, $V_{k}$ and $V_{K}$ are vector spaces of dimension $n$ over $k$ and over $K$, respectively. We have $V_{k} \subset V_{K}$, and we may identify $V_{K}$ with the tensor product $V_{k} \otimes K$ taken over $k$; $\mathfrak{g}$ operates in an obvious manner on $V_{K}$, and $V_{k}$ consists of the elements of $V_{K}$ which are invariant under $\mathfrak{g}$.

I am attaching here snaps of the paper for reference : [Pertaining to the first quotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwymN.png),
[Pertaining to the second quotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbId2.png)

**Note:** We are under the following setting: We have fixed a universal domain of characteristic $0$, a groundfield $k$ inside it and a normal extension $K$ of $k$ of finite degree $d$, with Galois group $\mathfrak{g}$

1. In the case of varieties, if we only think of affine varieties classically then we know they are embedded in some ambient space, so if $V$ is a variety over universal domain $U$, say, then we can think  of $V$ sitting inside $U^{m}$ for some $m$, and then it makes sense to say that $V_{k}$ is the set of points of $V$ with coordinates in $k$. But in the case of vector spaces, I don't understand what connection do $V, V_{k}$ and $V_{K}$ share? They are not just same as sets I guess. One way I could think of this was that I thought of $V$ as $U^{n}$ (as a vector space of dimension $n$ over $U$, the universal domain) and then $V_{k}, V_{K}$ are just the set of points in $U^{n}$ with coordinates in $k, K$ respectively.
2. I am not able to see how exactly to identify $V_{K}$ with $V_{k} \otimes K$ if I go by my definition as in 1. My attempt was to construct the following linear function from $V_{k} \otimes K$ to $V_{K}$ sending $(x_{1}, x_{2}, ...., x_{n}) \otimes c \mapsto (cx_{1}, ..., cx_{n})$ and extending this linearly. Now both domain and codomain have the same dimension over $K$, so proving that this is one-one suffices to show the isomorphism. I got stuck here.
3. I think the action of $\mathfrak{g}$ on $V_{K}$ is given by $\sigma(v \otimes c) = v \otimes \sigma(c)$. Using this definition of action, I couldn't prove that $V_{k}$ is the set of elements of $V_{K}$ invariant under $\mathfrak{g}$. One direction is trivial, in the other direction I had problems because of the fact that $m \otimes n = 0$ doesn't imply that $m= 0$ or $n= 0$.

I seek serious help with the above mentioned doubts, if anyone has any idea about any of it, please help. I would be grateful for the help. I am quite unsure what tags to use, feel free to add the relevant ones.

**Update:** (i) I got $3.$ figured out, since we are in a vector space, $m \otimes n = 0$ would indeed imply that $m = 0$ or $n = 0$.

(ii) In $2.$ instead of proving one-one, I proved it is onto like this : So, if we have a vector $(x_{1}, x_{2}, ..., x_{n})$ in the codomain, then consider the element $\sum_{i} e_{i} \otimes x_{i}$ in the domain of the function, its image is exactly $(x_{1}, x_{2}, ..., x_{n})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like think about this. If $X$ is a variety over $\mathbb{C}$ then the notation $X(\mathbb{Q})$ doesn't make sense as you yourself have noted in the first quote. But, if you say "Let $Y$ be a variety over $\mathbb{Q}$ and an isomorphism $i:Y_\mathbb{C}\to X$" then you can take $X(\mathbb{Q})$ to just mean $Y(\mathbb{Q})$ and, via the isomorphism $i$, you can think of $X(\mathbb{Q})$ as a subset of $Y(\mathbb{C})$.

Of course, what $Y$ you choose, and even what $i$ you choose, matters. For example, if $X=\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{C}}$ (the multiplicative group over $\mathbb{C}$) then you could take $Y_1=\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{Q}}$ or $Y_2=\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2+1))$. Both of these are models for $X$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and certainly have different $\mathbb{Q}$-points inside of $X(\mathbb{C})$.

Similarly, if you have a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$ it doesn't make sense to consider its '$\mathbb{Q}$-points' without choosing a model of $V$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. What is a model? Well, if $X=\text{Spec}(A)$ is an affine variety then a model over $\mathbb{Q}$ is an affine shcme $Y=\text{Spec}(B)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $Y_\mathbb{C}\cong X$. But, this just means that $B\otimes_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{C}\cong A$. In other words, you need to choose a $\mathbb{Q}$-subalgebra $B$ of $A$ such that the inducd map $B\otimes_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{C}\to A$ is an isomorphism.

So, it makes sense then that a model of $V$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is a subspace $V_\mathbb{Q}$ of $V$ such that the induced map $V_\mathbb{Q}\otimes_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{C}\to V$ is an isomorphism. Note though that if we choose a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis $\{e_\alpha\}$ of $V_\mathbb{Q}$ then the map $V_\mathbb{Q}\otimes_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{C}\to V$ is just the map

$$v\otimes \alpha\mapsto \alpha v$$

which has image precisely $\text{Span}(\{e_\alpha\})$. From this it's not hard to see that the condition on $V_\mathbb{Q}$ can be phrased precisely as the condition that it's spanned over $\mathbb{Q}$ by a $\mathbb{C}$-basis of $V$.

I hope that this was enough to help clear the confusion.

I would suggest you look at [this](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AG16.pdf) note by Milne which discusses these things at more depth. Specifically, your title question is then Lemma 16.5. You can also see Ben Blum-Smith's discussion when sorting through this note of Milne [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3173249/invariant-subspace-in-k-otimes-v-is-generated-by-invariant-vectors).

Comment: I am not very (in fact, not at all) familiar with the notion of schemes, etc. For the purpose of this paper, I merely acquainted myself with the classical treatment of varieties as done in Humphrey's Linear Algebraic Groups. But I think I understand what you mean, so like we can't talk of '$\mathbb{Q}$-points' of a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space V, but we can make a model of it over $\mathbb{Q}$ which is isomorphic to $V$, but can you explain what field this isomorphism is defined over?

Comment: @P-addict It's defined over the big field. So, the isomorphism $V_\mathbb{Q}\otimes_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{C}\cong V$ is an isomorphism of $\mathbb{C}$-spaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time, I got it!!